# Обработать html форму в Python

Tags: python, django, http

```html
<form action="Скрипт Python?" method="post">
  <p><b>Введите ваш текст:</b></p>
  <p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text"> </textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
```

Есть html форма. Как мне обработать request в скрипте python, не используя django forms и прочее?

Comment: Если не используя прям вообще ничего кроме веб-сервера, гуглите WSGI

Comment: @andreymal спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с помощью Django (он у вас в тегах), но без форм, то можно так:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'some_view.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST['text']
        # Обрабатываете текст как вам угодно
        return redirect('some_view')
```

Comment: спасибо большое!